# Awesome WM poor font rendering(thin)

Tags: x11, fonts, awesome

I'm using awesome 3.5 on Fedora 20 and the font rendering on the task bar is really bad:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOE0Y.png

I have

```
    Xft.dpi:96                                                                                       
    Xft.antialias:1                                                                      
    Xft.hinting:1                                                                        
    Xft.hintstyle:hintslight                                                             
    Xft.rgba:rgb                                                                         
    Xft.lcdfilter:lcddefault
```

Inside of my .Xresources and my .fonts.conf looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
 <fontconfig>
     <match target="font">
         <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
             <const>none</const>
         </edit>
     </match>
     <match target="font">
         <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
             <bool>true</bool>
         </edit>
     </match>
     <match target="font">
         <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
             <const>hintmedium</const>
         </edit>
     </match>
     <match target="font">
         <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
             <bool>true</bool>
         </edit>
     </match>
 </fontconfig>
```

I'm using Tamsyn 9, but this happens with all the fonts. Is there any way to get better font rendering?

Answer (score 1):

First, X resource settings are overridden by $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf - use one or the other to minimize confusion. See [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources#Xft_resources). I'll assume for the remainder of this answer that you're using X resources.

Next, fontconfig supports several hinting styles - try `hintnone`, `hintmeduim` or `hintfull` if you don't like `hintslight`. See [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Hintstyle).

Finally, make sure your DPI is set correctly. You can compute what it ought to be by dividing your screen resolution by its physical dimensions, which are obtainable via `xrandr`. See [3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Display_size_and_DPI).

Note: ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated - use $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fontconfig/fonts.conf instead if you'd rather not use X resources. See [4](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Fontconfig_configuration).